# String cannot be cast to javax.jcr.Value

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

I am getting the following error `String cannot be cast to javax.jcr.Value` when I try to set a properties for the JCR node using the following code.
The javax.jcr.Node.setProperty(String name, Value value) expects value for the "value" parameter but the casting does not work.

```java
// using for-each loop for iteration over Map.entrySet() 
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) { 
    try {
        //fetch the value of uuid mapped to the key "jcr:uuid"
        String uuid= (String) map.get("jcr:uuid");
        //get the JCR workspace session value for website
        Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession(RepositoryConstants.WEBSITE);
        //get the JCR node specified by the given identifier
        Node node = session.getNodeByIdentifier(uuid);

        //verify if the value for the specific value is of type HashMap
        //this means we have a nested map which denotes another node
        if (entry.getValue() instanceof HashMap ) {
            System.out.println("New node: " + entry.getKey());
            //Creates a new node at relPath of the specified node type
            node.addNode(entry.getKey(),NodeTypes.Page.NAME);
            //initializes a new map that points to the nested map
            HashMap<String , Object> newmap = (HashMap<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
            //recursion happens here
            loadMap(newmap);

        } else {
            //Sets the single-value property for all entries to the specified value.

            node.setProperty(entry.getKey(), (Value)entry.getValue()); ---> *error here*
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                            ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
        }       
    } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the solution thanks to @Ducaz035

```
String value= (String)entry.getValue();
node.setProperty(entry.getKey(), value);
```

Comment: Well I feel that the message is self explanatory. You cannot cast a String to your object *Value*. Maybe try to use a constructor of *Value* ?

Comment: What are you putting into the `map`? According to the error msg, those are `String`s and thus can't be cast to Value.

Comment: I am trying to put a string into a value. The error is very self explanatory but I do not know what is the workaround. The value I get is a string.

Comment: Did you try using `ValueFactory.createValue(java.lang.String value)`? That's what I've been able to find but I never used JCR so I have no idea if it works or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use `javax.jcr.Node#setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` directly. In fact, it accepts String as a value.

The problem in your code is not about String or Value but you try to insert Object, maybe cast Object to String and then set the property